# Show Modal Bottom Sheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, show, showmodaldialog, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

How to increase height of show modal bottom sheet.I can't get this any longer than this.Can somebody help me to solve my problem.

I tried bunch of solutions but non of them worked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please donot post the scrrenshot of the code, Instead copy and paste the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case wrap your container with column widget.It may increase bottom sheet's height.

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (builder) {
      return Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.90,
        child: Center(child: ADD_YOUR_WIDGET_HERE()),
      )
    ],
  );});
```

Note:If you want your bottom sheet in full screen you can wrap column in expanded widget.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `isScrollControlled: true` this parameter and add height to your widget then you can change the height of your Bottom sheet

```
   showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (builder) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.90,
        child: Center(child: ADD_YOUR_WIDGET_HERE()),
      );
    });
```

Try with this